# How to create a JavaScript logic for the below Json format

Tags: javascript, json

Am writing a JS logic to form the below Json format structure which i need to pass as a parameter to a REST GET call.

```
{  
   "abc":{  
      "name":"abcname"
   },
   "def":{  
      "name":"defname",
      "type":"xyz"
   },
   "employees":{  
      "size":"4000000000"
   },
   "recommend":{  
      "range":"456"
   }
};
```

when i write the below logic it gives me an extra " character before and after {}

```js
var abcObject = new Object();
abcObject.name = "abcname";
var abcjsonObject = new Object();
abcjsonObject.abc = JSON.stringify(abcObject);;
var myString = JSON.stringify(abcjsonObject);
console.log("myString" + myString);
```

Comment: can you show me your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only stringify the top level object/value. Replace

```
abcjsonObject.abc = JSON.stringify(abcObject);
```

with

```
abcjsonObject.abc = abcObject;
```

---

FWIW, more streamed lined way of creating the object would be

```
var abcjsonObject = {abc: {name: 'abcname'}};
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonObj = new Object();
jsonObj.name = "abcname";
var abcjsonObj = new Object();
abcjsonObj.abc = jsonObj;
console.log(JSON.stringify(abcjsonObj));
```